# C++: std::ifstream ifs(path), 'path should be a constant'

Tags: c++, fstream

I want something like this to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
std::string path;
char c;
while (true) {
    cin >> path;
    std::ifstream ifs(path);
    c = ifs.get();
    while (ifs.good()) {
        cout << c << endl;
        c = ifs.get();
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

It should ask for path, and then write out everything that is in the file. But it says the path should be a constant. How can I solve it? Maybe I should change the way I reach the file? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options (that I know):

1. use c++11 (adding std=c++11 compiling flag)
2. change `std::ifstream ifs(path)` with `std::ifstream ifs(path.c_str())`. This is because [`std::ifstream` constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/) takes as input `const char*` and you can get this from your string using the [`c_str()` method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) from `std::string` class.

Comment: As of C++11 this is no longer necessary.

Comment: I did not know. However, Nick might not be using c++11 otherwise he would not be getting such error. I have added the c++11 option.

Comment: I use visual c++ 2010